# Creating POS software with C# for POSTEK G-2108 printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing, barcode

My client want my program (a database reader program)
to print all the data (in the program) to be a label in a paper roll.

They want the program can print with their printer (a barcode printer POSTEK g-2108)
I have finished designing the program but when it comes to "print" it confuse me
I've never designed a POS software and create a specialy "layout" printing before

What the first thing I should do?
I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET v4 Framework

Comment: It's hard to tell, because nearly every printer (or at least every company) got their own api. Get the dlls and a documentation how to print form POSTEK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to your question. You need to interface with the POS device. You usually do this by using their API (.dll). That API then interfaces with the devices driver and does the things you tell it to do. If their .dll is written in C/C++ You can use `DllImport` so you can call the functions it exposes from C#.

Can't really tell you anything else, learn the API the manufacturer provides and then use it.

Good luck

Comment: thank you for the answer,i have take a look at `Dllimport` (i cant call the .dll directly),so i should begin  to code like this

`public class Postek
    {
        [DllImport("./postek.dll")]
        some code here ... `

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past by using the Microsoft POS for .net layer

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5355

As long as your printer has a compatible driver, it's a much easier way of interfacing.

Comment: I have download Microsoft POS for .net,but for some reason i barely understand from a documentation( especially Microsoft POS documentation)
do you have a sample or demo code?

Comment: If you install the full download, you get samples/demo code installed in the SDK directory that are very helpful.

Comment: And how about the special "layout" printing(for label)
how can you designed it?